# How can I push an element of array in desired position in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an array named 'arr' with four elements.

```
var arr = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "elephant"];
```

How can I push an element in the exact location (here, [3])? The results should be:

```
var arr = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use splice:

```
arr.splice(2, 0, "cat");
```